# How can I setup 2fa on iphone with 1 phone?

Tags: iphone

When setting up my refurbished iphone se, it wants a phone # for 2fA... I have one phone. It's not sitting on a desktop, I carry it with me places.

The other option is to not use 2FA, which it cautions against. Am I expected to carry 2 phones with me? Or, how is this expected to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the 2FA is for accessing Apple iCloud services. One factor is your iCloud password. The other factor is the phone in your hand. So give them the phone number of your iPhone se.

To log into the iPhone se you will use your phone pin or fingerprint. Not 2FA.

But any time you activate a new Apple device, you will authenticate with your iCloud password and iPhone se.

Comment: Ah.  This was while setting up the phone for the first time. I didn't think I had a phone  ready to receive calls at that point.